# psycopg2 inserting rows as columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I'm not sure if I'm articulating this correctly, but when querying data from one DB and inserting it into another using `psycopg2`, at some point the script is breaking up the data, and inserting the rows as columns (i.e. printing one character per column per row) as such:

```
     name     | id_2       | id_1        | blank        | data
--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------------
 A            | 1          | a           |              | {json: data}
 B            | a          | 1           |              | {json: data}
 C            | 2          | b           |              | {json: data}
 D            | b          | 2           |              | {json: data}
 E            | 3          | c           |              | {json: data}
 F            | c          | 3           |              | {json: data}
```

where I would expect the table to look like the following:

```
     name     | id_2       | id_1        | blank        | data
--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------------
 ABCDEF       | 1a2b3c     | a1b2c3      |              | {json: data}
```

The code I have to produce this is:

```
import psycopg2, uuid

id_1 = str(uuid.uuid4())

conn1 = psycopg2.connect(
    host='host',
    database=db1,
    user='user',
    password='password')

conn2 = psycopg2.connect(
    host='host',
    database=db2
    user='user',
    password='password')

def generate_data(id_1, name, id_2):

    data = {
        "tag": name,
        "id_2": id_2,
        "id_1": id_1,
        "rand_int": random.randint(0, 86400),
        "rand_uni_1": str(round(random.uniform(0.0, 8.0), 2)),
        "rand_uni_2": str(round(random.uniform(0.0, 16.0), 2)),
        "digi": "",
        "point_type": random.randint(0, 1),
        "garbage_data": "garbage_data"
    }
    data_str = str(json.dumps(data).replace("'", "''"))
    add_data(name, id_2, id_1, data_str)

def add_data(name_rec, id_2_rec, id_1_rec, data_rec):
    insert_data = "INSERT into table(name, id_2, id_1, data) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s::jsonb) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;"
    try:
        cur = conn2.cursor()
        cur.executemany(insert_data, zip(name_rec, id_2_rec, id_1_rec, data_rec))
        conn2.commit()
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn2 is not None:
            conn2.close()

def query_data():
    try:
        create_data_table()
        cur = conn1.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT name, table_name FROM existing_table;")
        data_returned = cur.fetchall()
        name = [i[0] for i in data_returned]
        old_table = [i[1] for i in data_returned]
        for x in data_returned:
            name = x[0]
            new_id_2 = x[1][5:].replace("_","-")
            generate_data(id_1_rec, name, new_id_2)
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)

def create_data_table():
    with conn2.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table "
            "("
            "name VARCHAR(100), "
            "id_2 VARCHAR(50), "
            "id_1 VARCHAR(50), "
            "data JSONB"
            ");"
        )
        conn2.commit()
    cursor.close()

create_data_table()
query_data()
```

I'm using the print statement to verify the data appears as it is supposed to be inserted into the table. I discovered this while isolating another issue I'm having with this code regarding `jsonb`, which I will be posting next. I'm relatively new to SQL and Python in general (as well as psycopg2) having come from QA so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does generate_data call add_data with id_1_rec, if there's no id_1_rec defined in generate_data (and it appears to not bel global)?

Comment: @Jeremy - that was a typo... I replaced a lot of the variables for added security measures. `add_data()` should be called with `id_1`, not `id_1_rec` so I fixed it above. That's that attention to detail!

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of writing functions and passing variables as arguments. Hence all the `print` statements. :)

Comment: Why not selecting the data from `existing_table` make it look the way you want instead of   're-inserting' into a new table ? And/or what's the difference between these 2 tables ? Probably, I don't really get the 'problem' at all :)

Comment: There have been some DB changes, and I've created this script to move data from one DB into another.

Comment: This is a mess, so I'm not really following what is going on. My suspicion is that the problem lies here: `cur.executemany(insert_data, zip(name_rec, id_2_rec, id_1_rec))`

Comment: On the bright side, I resolved the issue with the JSON I was having with this particular code!

Comment: @AdrianKlaver As previously mentioned, I'm relatively new to SQL and Python. :)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - I caught some of our devs after standup this morning, and that was indeed where the problem was so I've posted the resolution with explanation below. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caught some of our devs after standup this morning, and resolved this issue, which, if it isn't clear, is how the data is being entered into the DB as described above.

The issue here is with with the line `cur.executemany(insert_data, zip(name_rec, id_2_rec, id_1_rec, data_rec))` - more specifically the `executemany` method and the `zip()` function. Since the `zip()` function *returns a zip object, which is an iterator of tuples where the first item (and all subsequent items) in each passed iterator are paired together*,  and the `executemany` method *prepares a database operation (query or command) and executes it against all parameter sequences or mappings found in the sequence seq_of_params*, this was causing the data to be entered into the new table character by character. This was fixed by changing the line to `cur.execute(insert_data, (name_rec, id_2_rec, id_1_rec, data_rec))` And now my data appears as it should, i.e.

```
     name     | id_2       | id_1        | blank        | data
--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------------
 ABCDEF       | 1a2b3c     | a1b2c3      |              | {json:data}
```

My apologies for *messy* code and if I didn't initially articulate the issue correctly - I went to school for music and got into this field about 2.5 years ago as a QA with no prior experience so this is all still relatively new to me.